# Jacoco generate coverage report for only a single test class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

So let us say I have a test

```
@Test
public void testA(){
    new A().doSomthing();
}
```

And let us say it covers a method `doSomething()`, Now in my project, I have 10million tests and this test is just one of those. A small test doesn't do much.

Now let us say my `doSomething` method looks like this:-

```
public void doSomething() {
    if (var1)
        killMylSelf();
    else if (var2)
        killMyMother();
    else
        killMySelfAndMyMother();
}
```

So as you can see there are a lot of branches in the method, that consequently call other methods that have even more branches. When I run `testA` I want to see which branches I have missed in the code that got executed, how can I achieve this WITHOUT HAVING TO RUN ALL THE UNIT TESTS AND ONLY THE TEST THAT I CARE ABOUT,

Remember these magical words when you answer the question **WITHOUT HAVING TO RUN ALL THE UNIT TESTS AND ONLY THE TEST THAT I CARE ABOUT**

Comment: Have you tried configuring the maven or ant plugin using the `excludes` or `includes` options?

Comment: excludes and includes what? @NicoVanBelle

Comment: If you read the JaCoCo documentation, you see that most, if not all, goals can be configured with `excludes` and `includes` parameters. Here you can define what classes should be included or excluded from the coverage report.

Comment: I am using Maven and applied all the settings you mentioned, but unfortunately `mvn clean verify -Dtest=MyTestClassName#MyTestMethodName` does not create any test report or `site` folder in the `target` directory. There is no error and build successfully completed and the other folders are created in that directory. Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**JaCoCo does not execute your tests**, it simply records information  about what was executed. So execution of a tests, including case of a single test, is **entirely depends on a tool that you use to execute tests**, which unfortunately not mentioned in your question.

If you use **Maven** as a build tool, then execution of tests is usually done and controlled by `maven-surefire-plugin`, which has [option `test`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) to run individual test. Here is example:

`src/main/java/Example.java`:

```
public class Example {
  public void doSomething(int p) {
    if (p == 1) {
      a();
    } else {
      b();
    }
  }

  private void a() {
    System.out.println("a");
  }

  private void b() {
    System.out.println("b");
  }
}
```

`src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    new Example().doSomething(1);
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    new Example().doSomething(2);
  }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Execution of `mvn clean verify -Dtest=ExampleTest#test1` will produce following report in directory `target/site/jacoco`:

[image: coverage of test1]

and execution of `mvn clean verify -Dtest=ExampleTest#test2` will produce:

[image: coverage of test2]

which show coverage of `test1` and `test2` respectively.

For comparison - execution of all tests by `mvn clean verify` produces:

[image: coverage of all tests]

Note about usage of `clean`: File `target/jacoco.exec` contains execution information and used for generation of report ( see [agent option `destfile`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile) and [corresponding parameter of `jacoco-maven-plugin`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#destFile) ). By default JaCoCo agent appends to this files ( see [agent option `append`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) and [corresponding parameter of `jacoco-maven-plugin`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#append) ), so that `clean` is used in this example to prevent accumulation of data in this file about previous executions.

If you use **Gradle**, then it also [has similar ability](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering) - given same sources and `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

execution of `gradle clean test --tests ExampleTest.test1 jacocoTestReport` will produce report containing coverage of `test1`, which is the same as in case of Maven.

Similarly to example for Maven, `clean` is used in this example to prevent accumulation of data about previous executions in file `build/jacoco/test.exec` - [see `append` property of `JaCoCo Gradle Plugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_specific_task_configuration).

If you use **Eclipse IDE**, then there is [EclEmma Eclipse plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/) that integrates JaCoCo in Eclipse IDE and included by default in "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" starting from Oxygen (4.7) version. With it you can also get coverage of single test in Eclipse IDE - in editor right mouse click on a test name to get context menu and select "Coverage As -> JUnit Test".

Comment: Do I need to say gradle after mentioning android studio? Anyway a very comprehensive answer I like it, if the number of tests that run after executing your command exceeds one, I would be sourly disappointed :(, will give this a shot and let ou know in 12hours! Thanks for the help

Comment: @Bhargav search in browser on this page tells me that "android" was first time mentioned in your comment, but not in a question ;) Android is a bit different beast and I'm not an Android expert, but according to https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html "Android Plugin for Gradle" supports the same option "--tests" as "Gralde Java Plugin" that was mentioned in my answer for execution of single test.

Comment: @Bhargav And according to https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#view_test_coverage running a single test with coverage in Android Studio is possible and is not different than running test with coverage in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: the IDE doesnt report branch coverage sadly.

Comment: Sadly running `jacocoTestReport` triggers its `dependsOn` which executes all the Unit tests in the module :(

Comment: @Bhargav according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_tasks `jacocoTestReport` has no `dependensOn`. And again your initial question lacks clarity, because lacks concrete [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). While I'm pretty sure that there are many ways to bypass `dependsOn` eg. with new task without `dependsOn`, I'll stop suggestions, because sorry but in absence of concrete example I think that attempts to guess all aspects of your particular configuration are counterproductive and a kind of waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanations. I am using Maven and applied all the settings you mentioned, but unfortunately `mvn clean verify -Dtest=MyTestClassName#MyTestMethodName` does not create any test report or `site` folder in the `target` directory. There is no error and build successfully completed and the other folders are created in that directory. Any idea?